# Backing up Outlook files (.pst)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, data-recovery, onedrive, pst

I have scrolled through all the related questions to this problem. In short, I have emails from 2012 that need to be recovered; supposedly I have the back-up .pst file. However, this error reoccurs:
[".pst is not an Outlook Data file"]

I would also like to add that the size of the file is over 10gb, and I know that .pst files should not be over 2gb. I attempted to repair the backup file through Micrsoft's SCANPST if it could search through and find the error - I ran this three times. Does this mean that the file is severely corrupted... would third party repair tools fix this data?

Comment: You would have to try to recover the PST files.    Stellar Data Recovery has Outlook recovery tools.   I recommend these .   I have used these to recover Outlook files  (back in the time of Windows 7)

Comment: Of course, before trying to salvage anything from the .pst (or .ost) file, make a *copy*.

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you trying to open this PST file using? I echo John in support Stellar's software tools. It has been many years since I used them, but when I did, they worked well. Also, DrMoishe is right: You MUST copy the files and only work on the copies. Leave the originals alone for backup.

Comment: Thanks - Stellar Tools worked very well for me. I have PST Archives (multiple archives) all < 2 GB  going back to 1999 or a bit earlier and all still working.

Comment: The error message “.pst is not an Outlook Data file” means that the file you are trying to open is either corrupted, damaged, or not in the correct format.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? Please feel free to drop us a note if there is any update.